# swift python strange output

Tags: python, swift

I get this strange output when I run swift in terminal

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.1.2 (swiftlang-902.0.54 clang-902.0.39.2). Type :help for assistance.
```

Could somebody please help me solve this issue? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: That happens if you have a 3rd party Python (e.g. from Homebrew or MacPorts) in your path.

Comment: any suggestion how to solve that?

Comment: Did you have a look at the answer in the duplicate thread?

Comment: Had to figure out where the duplicate question was. Thank you very much!